# How to get statistics using Google Analytics Data

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-analytics-data-api

I wanted to bring statistics from Firebase to my website. To do this, I linked Firebase with Google Analytics in the settings in the ["Integrations" tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/paradox-website-cd25b/settings/integrations/analytics)

From there I copied the **Property ID**

Enabled Google Analytics Data API in my project

Then I replaced the **Property ID** with my own in [this script](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-analytics-data/blob/main/samples/quickstart.js) and ran the script.

But I got an error:

> Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment. To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit:https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Comment: did you forget to configure GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Comment: @DaImTo Interesting. Can you provide a link to the manual or documentation?

Comment: @DaImTo and to be honest, I would like to see the final result using node js

Comment: No but i can link you the issue request i just posted on the GitHub page for the library you are using telling them they should document it [#187](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-analytics-data/issues/187)  there is a link in the issue to where it is documented 

Comment: Btw you should always include [example] in your question rather then linking to it on an external site.   If that is ever changed then your question will become invalid.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks! Sorry for the impudence, it's just that the deadlines were pressing for the diploma, and I was stuck at this moment. And I don't know English well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you have not configured GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

You should be following the [API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#node.js)   it shows how to configure the credentials needed to authorize this code.

[image]

Once your authorization is configured you should be able to access this. Remember that the service account needs to be granted access to your google analytics account or it wont be able to access the property.

```
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment this variable and replace with your
   *   Google Analytics 4 property ID before running the sample.
   */
  // propertyId = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

  // Imports the Google Analytics Data API client library.
  const {BetaAnalyticsDataClient} = require('@google-analytics/data');

  // Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
  // specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
  const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

  // Runs a simple report.
  async function runReport() {
    const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [
        {
          startDate: '2020-03-31',
          endDate: 'today',
        },
      ],
      dimensions: [
        {
          name: 'city',
        },
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          name: 'activeUsers',
        },
      ],
    });

    console.log('Report result:');
    response.rows.forEach(row => {
      console.log(row.dimensionValues[0], row.metricValues[0]);
    });
  }

  runReport();
```